Nonlinear ODE $hh^{\prime\prime}=1+{h^{\prime}}^2$
I am reading elementary differential geometry written by O'neill.
In the explanation of catenoid,  we need find solution to $$hh^{\prime\prime}=1+{h^{\prime}}^2 $$ And this equation is known to be be solved by an elementary way. What is the way? Thank in advance.

Mathematica:  $$-\frac{e^{-c_1} \tanh \left(e^{c_1} (t+c_2)\right)}{\sqrt{-1+\tanh ^2\left(e^{c_1}
(t+c_2)\right)}}$$

@DavidG.Stork I am confused. For real parameters the denominator in your expression seems to be imaginary.

@Oscar:  You are correct.  I can imagine only that for forcing the solution to be real, one (or both?) of the constants must be complex.

The method I use does give real solutions with real parameters. Not having a single phase-shifted cosh function there is a bit clunky given the physics, but we can make that conversion using the sum formula for hyperbolic cosine andvthe fact that $|c_1|>|c_2|$.

There is a MathOverflow question about problems in which you introduce an "extra" operation (such as an extra camel in an old partitioning problem) to simplify its solution, with the intent to take that operation back at the end to restore the original problem conditions. This one qualifies.
Given your differential equation, you introduce ... an additional differentiation, with the intent to remove it by specifying the extra parameter this generates.
Thus
$hh''=1+(h')^2\implies h'h''+hh'''=2h'h''$
$hh'''=h'h''\implies (h''')/(h'')=(h')/h$
From the quotient rule for differentiation we know that $u'/u=v'/v$ implues $u/v$= constant, so we immediately have
$h''= \alpha h$
and immediately from the standard solution to the linear differential equation
$h=C_1\cosh(\sqrt\alpha x)+C_2\sinh(\sqrt\alpha x).$
To take back the extra "camel", we back substitute this into the original differential equation and identify a match with $\alpha=1/(C_1^2-C_2^2)$. Note that to complete the matching we should exchange $\sinh^2u$ for $\cosh^2u-1$.

Interesting.. are there more such examples in differentiation?

Differentiate $y''=-\exp(-y)$ to get $y'''=-y'y''$. Integrate once to render $y''=-\frac12y'+C_1$. Solve this by separation of variables for $y'$ as a function of $x$. Then you have $y''=-\exp(-y)$ as a function of $x$ and two integration constants $C_1,C_2$. Try it!

There are two relatively standard approaches.

Substitute $z=\log h$.

Set $w(x)=h'(x)$ and note that
$$\frac{dw}{dh} = \frac{\frac{dw}{dx}}{\frac{dh}{dx}}=\frac{h''(x)}{w(x)}=\frac{1+w^2}{hw}.$$



I am more comfortable with symbol $y$ rather than $h$ for the dependent variable, which is the same thing. Step by step procedure. Primes w.r.t. $x$
$y'$ should be made  the object variable derivative
$$ y'' = \frac{dy'}{dx}= \frac{dy'}{dy}~\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y' dy'}{dy} \tag1$$
Plug in the given
$$ y y^{''}=1+y^{'2} \tag 2 $$
$$ y \cdot \frac{y'~ dy'}{dy}=1+y^{'2} \tag 3$$
Multiply both sides by 2 and re-arrange
$$ \frac{2 y' dy'}{1+y^{'2}}=2 \frac{dy}{y} \tag 4 $$
Integrate, include a convenient constant
$$ \log(1+y^{'2})= 2 \log y - 2 \log c \tag 5 $$
$$ (1+y^{'2})= \frac{y^2}{c^2} \tag 6 $$
or
$$ y'=\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{c^2}-1} \tag 7 $$
$$ \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{c^2}-1}} = dx \tag 8 $$
Integrating
$$ c~ \cosh^{-1}\frac{y}{c}= x +c_1 \tag 9$$
Re-do the integration constant
$$ \cosh^{-1}\frac{y}{c}= \frac{x}{c} +c_2~ \tag {10} $$
$$ y= c  \cosh (\frac{x}{c}+c_2 ) \tag {11} $$
So the  even solution of the classic catenary is from $ c_2=0 $
$$ y =c \cosh\frac{x}{c}. \tag{12} $$

Hint
If you switch variables, the equation becomes
$$h\,x''+x' \left((x')^2+1\right)=0$$
Reduction of order $p=x'$  seems to lead to something simple at least for $x'$.

Let $p=h'$ and then
$$ h''=\frac{dh'}{dx}=\frac{dh'}{dh}\frac{dh}{dx}=p\frac{dp}{dh}. $$
So the equation
$$hh^{\prime\prime}=1+{h^{\prime}}^2 $$
becomes
$$ hp\frac{dp}{dh}=1+p^2. \tag1 $$
It is easy to see that (1) is equivalent to
$$ \frac{p}{1+p^2}dp=\frac{dh}h. \tag2 $$
Integrating (2) gives
$$ 1+p^2=C_1h^2 $$
or
$$ h'=\pm\sqrt{C_1^2h^2-1} $$
or
$$ \frac{dh}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{C_1^2h^2-1}. $$
So the solution is
$$ x=\pm\int\frac{dh}{\sqrt{C_1^2h^2-1}}+C_2=\pm\frac1{C_1}\text{arctanh}\bigg(\frac{C_1h}{\sqrt{C_1^2h^2-1}}\bigg)+C_2.$$
You can solve for $h$, which is not hard.I omit the detail.
